# Can't move minecraft character using pynput

Tags: python, minecraft, pynput

I'm trying to use Pynput to move my Minecraft character, but when I press run, it finishes without moving my character. I've retested it on stuff like the Minecraft chat and it works fine, I've also tested it on the Google Chrome search and it works, but weirdly not in Minecraft. My code is very simple.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import time

myKeyboard = Controller()
time.sleep(3)
myKeyboard.press('w')
myKeyboard.release('w')
time.sleep(3)
myKeyboard.press('s')
myKeyboard.release('s')
```

I don't see anything wrong with my code and I don't know if pynput even works with moving Minecraft characters, or any characters for that matter.

Comment: Maybe the key needs to be held for a particular length of time in order to have an effect?

Answer (score 2):

According to [pynput documentation](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html), keeping a button pressed is best used with the `pressed` method and a `with` statement, like this:

```
with myKeyboard.pressed('w'):
    time.sleep(3)
```

It should in theory hold the `w` key pressed for 3 seconds.